# A 'they' redundancy or not?

Tags: grammar

> In order to intellectually revolutionize the populace *they* must learn to see through the reformist deception of the academics.

Is that 'they' needed there?

I'm asking because it seems that in that sentence it is 'the populace' that 'must learn to see through the reformist deception of the academics.'

Comment: Yes, it's needed; _the populace_ is already the object of _revolutionize_, so it can't also be the subject of _must learn to see_. Hence the pronoun, which is the necessary subject. By the way, you need a comma between _populace_ and _they_ to separate the two clauses; it's necessary in the pronunciation, too.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, as  written,  the subject is most certainly **not** 'the populace. If it were, then the sentence would be reflexive, and better expressed as:

> In order to intellectually revolutionize *themselves*, the populace must learn to see through the reformist deception of the academics.

If 'the populace' were the subject, and 'they' stripped, the sentence could be written as follows:

> In order to intellectually revolutionize, the populace must learn to see through the reformist deception of the academics.

This sentence, however, leaves no direct object to be 'intellectually revolutionized.'

The seemingly correct interpretation, then, is that **'they' in the original sentence refers to a third party** with the potential to 'intellectually revolutionize the populace.' Most likely, this is a governing body of some sort. A comma between 'the populace' and 'they' is optional.

Comment: Hmm, I think it might mean: "*In order (for us) to intellectually revolutionize the populace, they, the populace, must learn to see through the reformist deception of the academics*".

Comment: Looking up the phrase leads to a bunch of Twitter links apparently attributing the quote to Socrates. Or Twitter accounts named Socrates. The same general structure is repeated with different subjects. "In order to intellectually revolutionize the students, they must learn to combat the brainwashing campaigns of the professors." -- With that context available, I would say it's a poorly phrased sentence. "In order to intellectually revolutionize the populace they must [first be made to] learn to see through the reformist deception of the academics." Really, this is advice to teachers...

Comment: ...he's saying that, if one has interest in intellectually revolutionizing the populace, one must first teach that populace of the deception of the academics.

Answer (score 1):

The formulation of the sentence is stylistically not optimal. Between "populace" and "they" a part is lacking, e.g. "it is necessary to tell them that they must learn ...".

**they referring to populace**

It is a characteristic of English that singular nouns denoting person groups such as team, staff, police etc can be connected with a verbform in plural and the pronouns "they/them/their" when the focus is on the members of the team/staff/police. And such person groups can also be used as a genuine singular as a collective noun.

You can say

1 The police are coming.

or

2 The police is coming.